# How to apply an active css class to li based on its child <a> href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following markup to show a navigation menu :

```
<ul class="nav sf-menu">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">Home<span></span></a></li>
```

Now I want to add `active` class to the `li` if the current URL is equal to its `<a>` href.

I have tried the following:

```
$(function () {

    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there
    // now grab every link from the navigation
    $('.sf-menu li').each(function () {
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
        if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });

});
```

but I get an error that `li` does not have a `href`. How do I get this to work?

Comment: try this `$('.sf-menu li>a').each(function () {
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
        if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });`

Comment: @Sushil i wrote the following "$('.sf-menu li>a').each(function (){
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
            if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) { $(this).parent().addClass('active'); }
        });" but this cause all the nav to have the active class

Comment: @Sushil your code will work if i am not at the root,, if i am at the root then all the li will be active..

Answer (score 3):

The href attribute exists on the `<a>` element, not the `<li>` element. You need to check the `<a>` for the href and then apply the class to the parent `<li>`.

Here is how I have tweaked your code to target the `<a>` tag:

```
jQuery(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname;

    if (url == '/') {
        jQuery('.sf-menu li > a[href="/"]').parent().addClass('active');
    } else {
        var urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");
        jQuery('.sf-menu li > a').each(function () {
            if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
                jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3cn5sy1/2/)**

I've also placed a check for if the link is `/` to prevent all the links from being marked as active.

You could also try this simplified version if your links work with it:

```
jQuery(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    jQuery('.sf-menu li > a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: this partially work now if i navigate to the About page "http://ABC/About" then the About link will be active correctly. but if i navigate to the root "http://ABC" then all the li will be active ..

Comment: That would mean the regex isn't quite right. Looks like it's doing a partial match. I'll try some tests and see if I can fix the regex up.

Comment: Actually, from my testing this seems to work correctly for me. I can't recreate your issue. I have a bunch of links in a `ul` list with sub lists. The sub links have nested urls like your example. Going to the parent page only that `li` gets the _active_ class. None of the children pages do. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3cn5sy1/) showing it working. Click _run_ to get it to make the url /_display/ . Can you recreated the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: but did not work in my case as when i am inside the root (the home page) all the links got selected. now i try the following " $('.sf-menu li > a').each(function () {
        if (str == this.href.toLowerCase()) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');//("class", "active"); //hightlight parent tab
        }" and it worked well,, not sure if this code is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.sf-menu li >a').each(function () {
```